# Load a random level, but not the same one?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I have a game where there are multiple rounds. Each round has a different map and at the end of the round a *random* scene is loaded from a list of scenes. I have a list of scenes like:

```
Arena 1
Arena 2
Arena 3
Arena 4
Arena 5
```

And I randomly load them when the round is over using this line of code:

```
Application.LoadLevel("Arena " + Random.Range(1, LEVEL_COUNT));
```

where `LEVEL_COUNT` is the max number of scenes I have.

This works fine, except sometimes when the round is over, the same scene that has just been played reloads. Say if you play `Arena 3` and the round is over, `Arena 3` may reload again.

So, is it possible to load a random scene like I am doing, but not load a scene that is the same scene we have just played? So load anything BUT `Arena 3` in this case.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not the same question as the duplicate. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are saying that you can repeat scenes, but not consecutively, is that correct? So you could play Arena 3 multiple times, as long as there is another scene in between each time.

If that's the case, then I would do it like so:

```
//Store the current scene in an integer. Set to zero by default.
int previousScene = 0;
```

The first time you get your random scene, there are LEVEL_COUNT number of scenes to choose from. But thereafter, since you can't repeat the scene, it's actually LEVEL_COUNT - 1.

```
//Randomly load the scene
int nextScene;
if(previousScene == 0)
    nextScene = Random.Range(1, LEVEL_COUNT);
else
    nextScene = Random.Range(1, LEVEL_COUNT - 1);
```

Every time the RNG returns a level that is the same or higher as the previous level, just add 1 to it. Then store the previous scene, and repeat.

```
if(nextScene >= previousScene){
    nextScene = nextScene + 1;
}
Application.LoadLevel("Arena " + nextScene);
previousScene = nextScene;
```